# Pentaho excel input from multiple sheets to textfile

Tags: excel, pentaho

I have an Excel workbook with dept figures from each department on different sheets.
I want to read all figures from each sheet and write them to rows in a text file with sheetname (dept name) as first column. Is this possible? When I set up an Excel Input and add selected sheets to the import I only get one of them and I also can't figure out how to attach the sheet name as a row in the output textfile. All sheets are the same, they differs from the sheet name.

The output text file should be like this:

Sheetname1;Sheet1:A1;Sheet1:B1

Sheetname1;Sheet1:A2;Sheet1:B2

Sheetname2;Sheet1:A1;Sheet1:B1

Sheetname2;Sheet1:A2;Sheet1:B2

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may use multiple Excel Inputs with almost the same configuration, but the sheet name and start of your data.

After each input step is ready you can fix the metadata and order of columns so they match perfectly with each other. Then just do a union with any step, I like to use the Dummy for that.

Example:

[image: Pentaho Multiple inputs, Dummy as a "Append Streams"]

Answer (score 0):

Case closed, the funcionality is out of the box. I had set the limit field because I thought it was the limit for each sheet and not for all rows to be read from all sheets. One nice feature would have been to be able to set the number of rows to be read on each sheet. I also found the Additional output fields tab where I found the sheetname field so now that case is closed as well.